# Integrating drag force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, integration, drag

I need help with an integration problem. We have $F_d = \frac{1}{2} \rho c_d Av^2$ and $$W = \int F_d\cdot dx = \frac{1}{2}\rho c_dA\int v^2\cdot dx = \frac{1}{2}\rho c_dA\int(\frac{dx}{dt})^2\cdot dx.$$ I need to find this integral to find the drag coefficient. I tried integration by parts which didnt work. Any tips?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do here. If you want to determine the drag coefficient, you need to know $v$. For this you need to know all the forces acting on the object, not just the drag force. If on the other hand $v$ is constant (terminal velocity) the integral is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, $v=dx/dt$ isn't known from just your expression for the drag force. In general, you would find an expression for $v(t)$ using the differential equation, then integrate the force integral with respect to time by replacing $dx$ with $v dt$. Here's how it might be done:

First, assuming you have an object with mass $m$ that has an initial velocity $v_0$ experiences this drag force, and no other forces. Then, writing $F=ma$:

$$ma = -\frac{1}{2} \rho c_d A v^2$$
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = -\frac{\rho c_dA}{2 m} v^2$$

This differential equation can be solved by separation of variables:

$$\int_{v_0}^{v(t)} \frac{dv}{v^2} = \int_0^t -\frac{\rho c_d A}{2m}dt$$

$$\frac{1}{v_0} - \frac{1}{v(t)} = -\frac{\rho c_d A}{2m}t$$

$$v(t) = \frac{1}{1/v_0 + \rho c_dAt/2m}$$

In order to find the work, you would integrate as follows:

$$W = \int -\frac{1}{2} \rho c_d A v^2 dx = \int - \frac{1}{2} \rho c_d A v^2 (vdt)$$

$$ = -\frac{1}{2} \rho c_d A \int v^3 dt$$
$$ = -\frac{1}{2} \rho c_d A \frac{1}{\rho c_dA/m (\rho c_d At/2m + 1/v_0)^2} + C$$

which is just equal to $\Delta K = \Delta (\frac{1}{2} mv^2)$ as expected from the work-energy theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Other approaches might work better,

perhaps you could get $\frac{dv}{dt}$ (from $F=ma$) in terms of $v^2$ and go from there,

or put weight equals the drag at terminal velocity (if your equation is for a falling object).  The integration you are trying might not be the best way...

Comment: Hi @John. Your name came up when I was running queries regarding [this thread on meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13556/getting-a-better-understanding-of-how-and-why-off-topic-homework-like-questions). I suspect this reflects the fact that you're one of the clearest holders of a pro-homework view which isn't currently well represented on Meta. As such I would like to invite you to participate there $-$ every perspective is important.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty , thanks, comment has been left

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration due to gravity and drag is $\boxed{a = g - \beta v^2}$ where $\beta$ is some known factor. We can also find the terminal velocity $v_{\rm term} = \sqrt{g/\beta}$ where the body will no longer accelerate.

The direct integration of acceleration yields the drop distance and time as a function of speed

$$ t = \int \frac{1}{a} \,{\rm d}v = \frac{1}{2 \beta v_{\rm term}} \ln \left( \frac{v_{\rm term} - v}{v_{\rm term}+v} \right) \tag{1}$$

$$ x = \int \frac{v}{a} \,{\rm d}v =-\frac{1}{2 \beta} \ln \left(1 - \left( \frac{v}{v_{\rm term}} \right)^2  \right) \tag{2}$$

So at any time, you can reverse (1) to find the velocity. And from the velocity $v$, the kinetic energy is found $$T = \tfrac{1}{2} m v^2$$

Also from the velocity, the drop distance $x$ is found from (2), and thus the potential energy

$$ P = -m g x $$

Finally, the work expended by drag is simply the sum of the energies above (a negative value)

$$ W = T + P $$